# Connect swift to FirebaseDatabase

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Want to connect this code to FirebaseDatabase.
But I getting an error while Connecting to it.

Error :- Cannot convert value of type '[Datasnapshot]' to expected argument type 'UView'.

[image: FirebaseDatabase]

> Below is Code snippet of it.

```
import UIKit
import FirebaseDatabase
import FirebaseAuth

class HomeViewController: UIViewController, iCarouselDelegate, iCarouselDataSource 
{

@IBOutlet var carouselView: iCarousel!

        var snaps : [DataSnapshot] = []
        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()
            if let currentUserUid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid {
                Database.database().reference().child("posts").child("photoUrl").observe(.childAdded, with: { (snapshot) in
                    self.snaps.append(snapshot)
                    self.carouselView.reloadData()
                })
            }

            carouselView.type = .coverFlow
        }

        func numberOfItems(in carousel: iCarousel) -> Int {
            return snaps.count
        }

        func carousel(_ carousel: iCarousel, viewForItemAt index: Int, reusing view: UIView?) -> UIView {
            let tempView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 374, height: 417))
           tempView.addSubview(snaps)
            return tempView
        }

        func carousel(_ carousel: iCarousel, valueFor option: iCarouselOption, withDefault value: CGFloat) -> CGFloat {
            if option == iCarouselOption.spacing {
                return value * 2.1
            }
            return value
        }
        override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
            super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
            // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
        }
}
```

Comment: This question is unclear. You don't connect Swift to Firebase; Firebase is implemented as part of your project and if you follow the [Gettting Started](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/start) guide, Firebase functions will be available in XCode. Also, Firebase nor a DataSnapshot has anything to do with Views which is why they cannot be added as a subview. If we understood what you were attempting we may be able to help. Please update your question with an actual question and provide a use case of what you are attempting to do, and we'll take a look.

Answer (score 0):

The error clearly shows that you are adding snapshot value into UIView.

```
tempView.addSubview(snaps)
```

in above code snaps is an array of DataSnapshot Type.You can not add DataSnapshot array as a subview.

Comment: So how can i fix it? My goal is to access images from my database and display them on my HomeViewController like tinder with the Swipe-Fu